# How to return an array of char pointers? What is wrong in my code?

Tags: c, pointers

I have seen similar posts related to my question but I could not find any answer to understand the bug in this code.

So, I have a function whose return type can't be changed (for case 1). For case 2, I would like to know how to return `char *a[]`;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **myfunc(int n) {
    char **a = malloc(n * sizeof(char *));
    int i, j = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = malloc(9 * sizeof(char));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        snprintf(a[i], 5, "%d", i);
        return a;
    }

int main() {
    int num = 10, i;
    char **ar = myfunc(num);
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
        printf("%s\n", ar[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

1) In the `myfunc()`, how should I return `a` correctly? My compiler is throwing me a warning that return from incompatible pointer type.

2) In case, if I change my above `myfunc()` as follows, how should I return the modified buffer?

```
char ???myfunc(int n) {
    char *a[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));

   return ?
}
```

3) In both cases, how should I handle the return inside the `main()` function?

*Case 2:*

```
char *myfunc(int n) {
    static char *a[n];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = malloc(9 * sizeof(char));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        snprintf(a[i], 5, "%d", i);

    return a;
}

int main() {
    int num = 10, i;
    char *ar = myfunc(num);
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
        printf("%s\n", ar[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For the fist case, precisely what error are you getting? It complies fine with `gcc -Wall` once you correct your syntax errors and include the required headers. For the second, you are attempting to return an array of pointers that exists on the stack. The memory becomes invalid once `myfunc` returns.

Comment: You can find your answer in the reference [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118218/returning-an-array-of-char-pointers)

Comment: Please provide actual code. The first excerpt lacks necessary includes, has a syntax error **and** fails to produce your problem.

Comment: @Brian, you are right. On my Ubuntu machine, it runs fine.
but when I tried running using Codeblocks on Windows, I get this warning:

main.c|20|warning: return from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]|

Comment: @Саша I tried that method already.  I am getting an error
segmentation fault
Please refer to the case 2 code above.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Now, I have added the headers.
What is your environment? Mine is both Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: case 1 has mismatched braces, you have `int main()` while still inside`myfunc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was mis-indented, which makes it hard to read and hides silly mistakes such as the extra brace after the second `for`.

Once corrected for this mistake, the code compiles and runs fine:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **myfunc(int n) {
    char **a = malloc(n * sizeof(char *));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = malloc(9 * sizeof(char));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        snprintf(a[i], 9, "%d", i);
    return a;
}

int main() {
    int num = 10, i;
    char **ar = myfunc(num);
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
        printf("%s\n", ar[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

If you change `myfunc()` to define `a` as `char *a[n];`, you have a major problem when returning `a` from `myfunc()` as the array is defined only inside the scope of `myfunc()`. Returning its address, which is simply `return a;` will cause undefined behavior in `main()` because the space it points to might have been reused for other stuff, such as `printf()` local variables.

The third option where you define `a` as `static char *a[n];` does not compile because the size of static objects must be known at compile time. Using local `static` objects is not advisable as it makes the program harder to understand and non-reentrant, with hidden internal state, etc. One such function is `strtok()` from `<string.h>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. When I followed the static declaration, I faced exactly the same issues and guessed that if the array is declared non-static, it will not be available to the main function..

Comment: Another observation is, when I run this code on Ubuntu with gcc -Wall I don't have any warnings. But the same code on Codeblocks (Windows) throws an warning 
warning: return from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]|
for the statement return a;
What could be the reason?

Comment: @hago The prototype for case 2 is incorrect: the return type is `char *` and you return `a` defined as `static char *a[n];` if `n` is replaced with `10`, the return type should be `char **` too.